# How to boot Ubuntu 14.04 with grub4dos (RMPrepUSB)

Tags: 14.04, boot, live-usb, grub4dos

After downloading Ubuntu 14.04, I would run it from a bootable USB stick.

I already have the bootable USB stick with grub4dos, and I was looking for a 'guide post' with the command to boot Ubuntu 14.04. But I do not found.

My linux.lst (called by menu.lst) contains:

```
title Run Ubuntu 14.04
find --set-root /BOOT/Linux/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
map /BOOT/Linux/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso (0xff) || map --mem /BOOT/Linux/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/BOOT/Linux/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso quiet splash --
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

Error at Grub console:
*Error 15: File not found*

Why it not works? What is wrong?

Thnk you all.

*[Edited March 9, 2015 as @bummy guided me - Translated from Portuguese with Google Translate]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for a solution, I finally found the error and the correct code to boot it (it still works for me):

```
title Run Ubuntu 14.04
find --set-root /BOOT/Linux/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
map /BOOT/Linux/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso (0xff) || map --mem /BOOT/Linux/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/BOOT/Linux/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso quiet splash --
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

The mistake was the path to `ubuntu.seed`. The correct path is `/preseed` (rather than `/cdrom`).

Notes:

- It had not worked with an Ubuntu 12.04 (non-LTS) that I had here.
- Do not forget to change the path "/BOOT/Linux/ubuntu14.04.iso" to the path where your "ISO" file actually is.

*References: [http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/grub4dos](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/grub4dos_)*

Thank u all ;)

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 15.10, although `find --set-root` failed after loading ISO and I had to manually `root` appropriate disk.

Answer (score 2):

Both do not work.
Works only this variant:

```
title Install Ubuntu 14.04 amd64
find --set-root /iso/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
map --unmap=0:0xff
map --unhook
root (hd0,0)
map /iso/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso (0xff) || map --mem /iso/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso (0xff) || map --mem --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /iso/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/iso/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso quiet splash --
errorcheck off
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
errorcheck on
map --unmap=0:0xff
```

Comment: In my case, I did not need so many expressions. I just ran what I posted... and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the below menu.lst starts Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) on a 32-bit machine:

```
title Run Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit
find --set-root /ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso
map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso (0xff) || map --mem /ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz  file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso quiet splash --
initrd /casper/initrd.lz

title supergrub2disk iso
map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 (hd0,0)/super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.02s3.iso (hd32)
map --hook
chainloader (hd32)
boot
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me with `grub4dos`

```
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso quiet splash --

initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

seems similar to use - is ISO your corrupt?

Comment: It's exactly what I did, Steve. I can't remember if I've checked ISO's md5sum. However, as I said, the file "ubuntu.seed" was not found at "/cdrom" (as I saw in a code to boot Ubuntu 12.04, that was the only one closest Ubuntu 14.04). So, to let the solution public, I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

copy .disk, casper, preseed to flashdrive.

```
gedit menu.lst

title Try Ubuntu without installing
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper 
initrd /casper/initrd.lz 

title Ubuntu installing
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity boot=casper 
initrd /casper/initrd.lz`
```

tested on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Fabby, all of these files are in their places. But as I was looking for a Grub4dos boot code to boot Ubuntu 14, and I've found only codes for Ubuntu 12, I had to figure out what the code to boot Ubuntu 14. Inspecting the Grub's error logs, and the ISO's folders, I found the mistake: the path to "ubuntu.seed" was wrong. I fixed it and, with those code lines that I posted, Ubuntu 14 ran. Thx for answr!